# SQL: Group by attributes from one table but not the other in a join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Essentially I have 2 tables joined which I need to group by the attributes in the first table, but not the second.

I can do this...

```
SELECT "Table1".*
```

...to produce only the columns from the first table in the output. But the following results in an error when trying to group them...

```
GROUP BY "Table1".*
```

Is there a way to group them by the elements in the first table without typing all the individual columns in Table1?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres supports an ANSI feature called functional dependency.  So, if you have a unique id in `table1`, then you can aggregate by that:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
group by t1.id;
```

The `id` has to be declared correctly as either a primary key or unique key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SELECT DISTINCT to remove duplicate data

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Table1".*
```